# How to interact with page elements while crawling a website with PHP?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I need to go to http://butlercountyclerk.org/bcc-11112005/ForeclosureSearch.aspx, enter data in the fields, then click the button to get results. When taken to the result page, I'm given a table of data but it's paginated into 5 different pages.

I'm able to do the above using cURL, but it's at this point that I get stuck.

Once I'm on the result page, I need to click the "date" header twice to make the data order by decreasing date, then skim off the current day's results.

Any idea how to do this, advanced detail or in concept? Either way should help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't get a working set of results - if you could post some dummy data that gives results, that would help.

As a generic answer, you need something that can manipulate the DOM. You can go server-side with something like PHP and Webdriver, or purely client-side with Selenium. Simulate the click, get the resulting HTML and parse that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the click is actually performing a postback using javascript, with the limitations of PHP and cURL you will need to inspect the HTTP headers (GET, POST and COOKIES) being sent by the browser, and emulate them. Taking in mind that some values might be session dependent. Right now I don't have time to do this for you but I know it can be quite tricky with ASP.Net websites in some cases. There might be easier ways to do it, but that's what it will always come down to, because that's what happens.

If you weren't tied to PHP a whole world of options open - for example, the aggregator in the project I'm working on is actually capable of executing (controlled) javascript specifically for these kinds of tasks/pages (albeit on a grander scale).

Answer (score 0):

This should work. try this.

```
$url    ='http://butlercountyclerk.org/bcc-11112005/ForeclosureSearch.aspx';

## do curl , with cookies enabled.


## after do this.

$url    =$url.'?'.'__EVENTTARGET=Search%3AdgSearch%3A_ctl2%3A_ctl1&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=dDwtMjk2Mjk5NzczO3Q8O2w8aTwxPjs%2BO2w8dDw7bDxpPDE%2BOz47bDx0PDtsPGk8Mz47aTwxNz47aTwxOT47PjtsPHQ8dDw7cDxsPGk8MD47aTwxPjtpPDI%2BO2k8Mz47aTw0PjtpPDU%2BOz47bDxwPDIwMDY7MjAwNj47cDwyMDA3OzIwMDc%2BO3A8MjAwODsyMDA4PjtwPDIwMDk7MjAwOT47cDwyMDEwOzIwMTA%2BO3A8MjAxMTsyMDExPjs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VmlzaWJsZTs%2BO2w8bzx0Pjs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BO3Q8QDA8cDxwPGw8Q3VycmVudFBhZ2VJbmRleDtQYWdlQ291bnQ7XyFJdGVtQ291bnQ7XyFEYXRhU291cmNlSXRlbUNvdW50O0RhdGFLZXlzOz47bDxpPDA%2BO2k8ND47aTwxMD47aTw0MD47bDw%2BOz4%2BOz47Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7PjtsPGk8MD47PjtsPHQ8O2w8aTwyPjtpPDM%2BO2k8ND47aTw1PjtpPDY%2BO2k8Nz47aTw4PjtpPDk%2BO2k8MTA%2BO2k8MTE%2BOz47bDx0PDtsPGk8MD47aTwxPjtpPDI%2BO2k8Mz47aTw0Pjs%2BO2w8dDw7bDxpPDA%2BOz47bDx0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7TmF2aWdhdGVVcmw7PjtsPENWIDIwMTEgMDUgMTQzNjtodHRwOi8vd3d3LmJ1dGxlcmNvdW50eWNsZXJrLm9yZy9wYS9wYS51cmQvcGFtdzIwMDAtb19jYXNlX3N1bT8xNjE3NzE0OSAgICAgICAgICAgIDs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BOz4%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8NS8zLzIwMTE7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPFNVTlRSVVNUIE1PUlRHQUdFIElOQzs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8TkFUSEFOSUVMIEdBQkJBUkQ7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPDEzNTQgVkFOREVSVkVFUiBBVkUgSEFNSUxUT04sIE9IIDQ1MDExOz4%2BOz47Oz47Pj47dDw7bDxpPDA%2BO2k8MT47aTwyPjtpPDM%2BO2k8ND47PjtsPHQ8O2w8aTwwPjs%2BO2w8dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0O05hdmlnYXRlVXJsOz47bDxDViAyMDExIDA1IDE0MTU7aHR0cDovL3d3dy5idXRsZXJjb3VudHljbGVyay5vcmcvcGEvcGEudXJkL3BhbXcyMDAwLW9fY2FzZV9zdW0%2FMTk2MzQ4ODUgICAgICAgICAgICA7Pj47Pjs7Pjs%2BPjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPDUvMi8yMDExOz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDxUSElSRCBGRURFUkFMIFNBVklOR1MgQU5EIExPQU4gQVNTTiBPRiBDTEVWRUxBTkQ7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPEdBWUxFIE5BU0g7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPDg5NDEgQ09YIFJEIFdFU1QgQ0hFU1RFUiwgT0ggNDUwNjk7Pj47Pjs7Pjs%2BPjt0PDtsPGk8MD47aTwxPjtpPDI%2BO2k8Mz47aTw0Pjs%2BO2w8dDw7bDxpPDA%2BOz47bDx0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7TmF2aWdhdGVVcmw7PjtsPENWIDIwMTEgMDUgMTUwMztodHRwOi8vd3d3LmJ1dGxlcmNvdW50eWNsZXJrLm9yZy9wYS9wYS51cmQvcGFtdzIwMDAtb19jYXNlX3N1bT8yMjY1MTYxMiAgICAgICAgICAgIDs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BOz4%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8NS85LzIwMTE7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPFUgUyBCQU5LIE4gQTs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8TE9VSVMgTUlSTUFOOz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDw2OTkxIEdBUlkgTEVFIERSIFdFU1QgQ0hFU1RFUiwgT0ggNDUwNjk7Pj47Pjs7Pjs%2BPjt0PDtsPGk8MD47aTwxPjtpPDI%2BO2k8Mz47aTw0Pjs%2BO2w8dDw7bDxpPDA%2BOz47bDx0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7TmF2aWdhdGVVcmw7PjtsPENWIDIwMTEgMDUgMTQ5MjtodHRwOi8vd3d3LmJ1dGxlcmNvdW50eWNsZXJrLm9yZy9wYS9wYS51cmQvcGFtdzIwMDAtb19jYXNlX3N1bT8yMzk3NTc5MiAgICAgICAgICAgIDs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BOz4%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8NS82LzIwMTE7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPEZJRlRIIFRISVJEIE1PUlRHQUdFIENPOz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDxSQVlNT05EIFNURUlOOz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDwyMzU5IFRIUlVTSCBBVkUgRkFJUkZJRUxELCBPSCA0NTAxNDs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BOz4%2BO3Q8O2w8aTwwPjtpPDE%2BO2k8Mj47aTwzPjtpPDQ%2BOz47bDx0PDtsPGk8MD47PjtsPHQ8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDtOYXZpZ2F0ZVVybDs%2BO2w8Q1YgMjAxMSAwNSAxNDM4O2h0dHA6Ly93d3cuYnV0bGVyY291bnR5Y2xlcmsub3JnL3BhL3BhLnVyZC9wYW13MjAwMC1vX2Nhc2Vfc3VtPzI0NzgyOTYzICAgICAgICAgICAgOz4%2BOz47Oz47Pj47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDw1LzMvMjAxMTs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8V0VMTFMgRkFSR08gQkFOSyBOIEE7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPEpBTkVUIEJPRUhNOz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDw4NjA4IEdPTERGSU5DSCBXQVkgV0VTVCBDSEVTVEVSLCBPSCA0NTA2OTs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BOz4%2BO3Q8O2w8aTwwPjtpPDE%2BO2k8Mj47aTwzPjtpPDQ%2BOz47bDx0PDtsPGk8MD47PjtsPHQ8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDtOYXZpZ2F0ZVVybDs%2BO2w8Q1YgMjAxMSAwNSAxNDQwO2h0dHA6Ly93d3cuYnV0bGVyY291bnR5Y2xlcmsub3JnL3BhL3BhLnVyZC9wYW13MjAwMC1vX2Nhc2Vfc3VtPzI1NTkwMjAzICAgICAgICAgICAgOz4%2BOz47Oz47Pj47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDw1LzQvMjAxMTs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8RklGVEggVEhJUkQgQkFOSzs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8VEhFT0RPUkUgQ09PSzs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8UE8gQk9YIDE3MTEgV0VTVCBDSEVTVEVSLCBPSCA0NTA3MTs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BOz4%2BO3Q8O2w8aTwwPjtpPDE%2BO2k8Mj47aTwzPjtpPDQ%2BOz47bDx0PDtsPGk8MD47PjtsPHQ8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDtOYXZpZ2F0ZVVybDs%2BO2w8Q1YgMjAxMSAwNSAxNDkwO2h0dHA6Ly93d3cuYnV0bGVyY291bnR5Y2xlcmsub3JnL3BhL3BhLnVyZC9wYW13MjAwMC1vX2Nhc2Vfc3VtPzI2ODY3MDkxICAgICAgICAgICAgOz4%2BOz47Oz47Pj47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDw1LzYvMjAxMTs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8Q0lUSUZJTkFOQ0lBTCBJTkM7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPERPTk5BIE1BUkRJUzs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8NjU0OSBDQU5BU1RPVEEgRFJJVkUgSEFNSUxUT04sIE9IIDQ1MDExOz4%2BOz47Oz47Pj47dDw7bDxpPDA%2BO2k8MT47aTwyPjtpPDM%2BO2k8ND47PjtsPHQ8O2w8aTwwPjs%2BO2w8dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0O05hdmlnYXRlVXJsOz47bDxDViAyMDExIDA1IDE0Njg7aHR0cDovL3d3dy5idXRsZXJjb3VudHljbGVyay5vcmcvcGEvcGEudXJkL3BhbXcyMDAwLW9fY2FzZV9zdW0%2FMjk4NzU2MDIgICAgICAgICAgICA7Pj47Pjs7Pjs%2BPjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPDUvNS8yMDExOz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDxDSVRJTU9SVEdBR0UgSU5DOz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDxNQVRUSEVXIEJMVU5ERUxMOz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDwxNDEyIEhFTE1BIEFWRSBIQU1JTFRPTiwgT0ggNDUwMTM7Pj47Pjs7Pjs%2BPjt0PDtsPGk8MD47aTwxPjtpPDI%2BO2k8Mz47aTw0Pjs%2BO2w8dDw7bDxpPDA%2BOz47bDx0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7TmF2aWdhdGVVcmw7PjtsPENWIDIwMTEgMDUgMTQzMjtodHRwOi8vd3d3LmJ1dGxlcmNvdW50eWNsZXJrLm9yZy9wYS9wYS51cmQvcGFtdzIwMDAtb19jYXNlX3N1bT8zMjI0MzYxNyAgICAgICAgICAgIDs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BOz4%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8NS8zLzIwMTE7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPFdFTExTIEZBUkdPIEJBTksgTiBBOz4%2BOz47Oz47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDxKT0hOIEJPV01BTjs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8Jm5ic3BcOzs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BOz4%2BO3Q8O2w8aTwwPjtpPDE%2BO2k8Mj47aTwzPjtpPDQ%2BOz47bDx0PDtsPGk8MD47PjtsPHQ8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDtOYXZpZ2F0ZVVybDs%2BO2w8Q1YgMjAxMSAwNSAxNDYzO2h0dHA6Ly93d3cuYnV0bGVyY291bnR5Y2xlcmsub3JnL3BhL3BhLnVyZC9wYW13MjAwMC1vX2Nhc2Vfc3VtPzQyMjcwMTE5ICAgICAgICAgICAgOz4%2BOz47Oz47Pj47dDxwPHA8bDxUZXh0Oz47bDw1LzQvMjAxMTs%2BPjs%2BOzs%2BO3Q8cDxwPGw8VGV4dDs%2BO2w8VSBTIEJBTksgTkFUSU9OQUwgQVNTT0NJQVRJT047Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPEJSWUFOIFNDSE1JRFQ7Pj47Pjs7Pjt0PHA8cDxsPFRleHQ7PjtsPDI4OTUgV0VFUElORyBXSUxMT1cgRFJJVkUgSEFNSUxUT04sIE9IIDQ1MDExOz4%2BOz47Oz47Pj47Pj47Pj47Pj47Pj47Pj47PtVTse1TdIXrxq%2FXrY%2Fp22QQ7pAh&Search%3AddlMonth=5&Search%3AddlYear=2011&Search%3AtxtCompanyName=&Search%3AtxtLastName=&Search%3AtxtCaseNumber=';

## DO curl with cookies on again
```